# Find the limit of $n \ln(\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n})$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit of
$\displaystyle\ n \ln\left(\ln\left(n + 1\right) \over \ln\left(n\right)\right)\ $ as $n$ tends to infinity.

I used L hospital's rule to find the limit, but it made the calculations complicated.

How to find this limit ?.
Any hint would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\log(1+1/n) < 1/n$ implies that $\log(n+1)< \log n +1/n.$ Hence, $$\log\log (n+1) < \log (\log n + 1/n) $$ 
$$= \log \log n + \log \Big(1+\frac{1}{n\log n}\Big)$$
$$<\log \log n + \frac{1}{n \log n}$$
Therefore,
$$ 0<n \Big(\log \log (n+1) - \log \log n\Big) <\frac{1}{\log n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using L'Hospital's rule, it is often more convenient to expand such composed functions via Taylor series or similar asymptic expressions.
Here,
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\ln(\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}) = 
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\ln(\frac{\ln(n)+\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^2})}{\ln(n)}) = \\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\ln (1 + \frac{1}{n\ln(n)} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^2})) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\ln (1 + \frac{1}{n\ln(n)} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^2})) = \\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\left( \frac{1}{n\ln(n)} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^2})\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{1}{\ln(n)} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})\right) = 0.$$
This basically always works, if your limit exists and your functions are well-behaved throughout. It gives you nice extra information, like speed of convergence. L'Hospital's rule has the theoretical upper hand, since the functions involved don't even have to be differentiable at zero, but it's messy and doesn't yield extra information.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  $\lim\dfrac {\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}=1$, because $\lim\ln n=\lim\ln (n+1)$.  Then use that $x^n$ and $\ln x$ are continuous.

The limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a bit more than the limit itself, using, as in other answers and comments, you compose Taylor series
$$y=\frac{\log (n+1)}{\log (n)}=\frac{\log (n)+\log \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\log (n)}=\frac{\log (n)+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) }{\log (n)}$$ that is to say
$$y\sim 1+\frac1{n\log (n)}-\frac1{2n^2\log (n)}+\cdots$$ Continuing with Taylor
$$\log\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log( n)}\right)=\log(y)=\frac{1}{n \log \left({n}\right)}-\frac{\log \left({n}\right)+1}{2
   n^2 \log ^2\left({n}\right)}+\cdots$$
$$n \log\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log( n)}\right)=\frac{1}{ \log \left({n}\right)}-\frac{\log \left({n}\right)+1}{2
   n \log ^2\left({n}\right)}+\cdots$$ Try it with your pocket calculator for $n=10$ (which is a bit far away from $\infty$). You should get $0.4056$ while the above truncated series would give $0.4031$.

Answer (score 0):

By Lagrange's theorem, since $\frac{d}{dx}\log\log(x)=\frac{1}{x\log x}$,
$$ \log\log(n+1)-\log\log(n) = \frac{1}{(n+\xi)\log(n+\xi)},\qquad \xi\in(0,1) $$
hence
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} n\left(\log\log(n+1)-\log\log(n)\right) = 0.$$